# Помощь с библиотекой requests

Tags: python, requests

С помощью библиотеки requests научился скачивать файлы, но возник такой вопрос, для соединения используется же `HTTP`, каким образом тогда происходит передача изображения или видео, к примеру? В коде самой библиотеки не копался.

И второй вопрос. Видел много примеров, где через `requests.post` предлагается, например логиниться, передавая пару логин - пароль в аргументах.
Но каким образом происходит понимание, куда именно их вставлять?

```py
requests.post('url', data={'key':'value'})
```

То есть, например, используем эту команду в простейшем текстовом виде, всё понятно, просто добавляет элементы в словарь, но в более сложных операциях не очень понимаю.

Comment: 1) Таким же, как и передача чего угодно другого; 2) Это нужно спрашивать у того, кто делал сервер и реализацию логина на нём

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Каждое `HTTP`-сообщение состоит из трёх частей, которые передаются в
>   указанном порядке:
>
> 1. Стартовая строка (англ. Starting line) — определяет тип сообщения;
> 2. Заголовки (англ. Headers) — характеризуют тело сообщения, параметры
>      передачи и прочие сведения;
> 3. Тело сообщения (англ. Message Body) — непосредственно данные
>      сообщения. Обязательно должно отделяться от заголовков пустой
>      строкой.

*<sub>Источник: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Структура_протокола](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0)</sub>*

---

Передача параметров методом `post` происходит через тело сообщения. Выглядит это примерно так же, как и в методе `get`:

```py
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

key=value&key2=value2
```

Файлы (изображения, видео и т. д.) передаются в двоичном представлении, при этом заголовок `Content-Type` имеет значение `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Со структурой протокола знаком.
А исполняемые файлы, к примеру .exe возможно таким образом отправлять?
Прошу прощения за глупые вопросы. Просто сама расшифровка HTTP вводит ступор, потому что вроде как гипертекст, а не файлы:)

Comment: @Benben Любые файлы будут переданы в двоичном представлении. Будь то фото или исполняемый файл.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ на первый вопрос:**

HTTP прекрасно справляется с выгрузкой файлов. Для этого и существует метод POST.
Выгрузка файлов описана в [RFC-1867](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt)

**Ответ на второй вопрос:**

Не очень понимаю, что вы имеете в виду под сложными операциями, однако...

Сервер тоже не пустой канал с ухом на конце, а он есть программа, в которой описан так называемый в обиходе *handler*, предназначенный для того, чтобы ожидать запросов извне и сразу же их обрабатывать. К примеру используя инструменты `FLASK` на Python можно написать простейший сервер, который принимает post-запрос, проверяет полученные данные и отправляет результат обработки пользователю. Результатом могут быть данные на сервере или же строка о закрытом доступе и неправильном пароле.

Мой рабочий пример:

```
...
@app.route( '/', methods = ['POST'])
def json_handler():
    data = request.json
    request_name = ""

    if data == None:
        with open("server_no_command.json") as f:
            return jsonify(json.loads(f.read()))

    try:
        if data['command'] == "create_or_update_config":
            with open("server_create_or_update_config.json") as f:
                return jsonify(json.loads(f.read()))
    except KeyError:
        pass

    try:
        if data['command'] == "delete_config":
            with open("server_delete_config.json") as f:
                return jsonify(json.loads(f.read()))
    except KeyError:
        pass
...
```

То есть проверяем значение по ключу в полученных данных и решаем, что делать дальше. Таким же простым образом можно проверить пару логин-пасс, имея грубо говоря словарик с имеющимися юзерами и их паролями на сервере:

```
    try:
        if data[data.keys()[0]] == loginpassbase[data.keys()[0]]:
            with open("server_create_or_update_config.json") as f:
                return jsonify(json.loads(f.read()))
        else:
            return jsonify({"message":"WrongPassword"})
    except KeyError:
        return jsonify({"message":"WrongLogin"})
```

Как-то так. Давно такие штуки не делал, строго не судите)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все понял:)

Comment: Не забудьте поставить галочку и стрелку вверх на ответ, который вам помог) В данном случае, я так понимаю, это второй ответ, который был дан раньше моего